# How do I fix this "Call to undefined method" error in Doctrine when using Symfony 2.3

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

When using Doctrine to generate a new ORM model in Symfony 2.3, I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Configuration::getAliasNamespaces()
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you can amend the **generate** function inside **//Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle/Generator/DoctrineEntityGenerator.php**.

Replace this line:

```
$config->getAliasNamespaces()
```

With this:

```
$config->getEntityNamespaces()
```

This appears to be a bug in Symfony 2.3. I found this on the Github forum [here](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/issues/199), but this doesn't appear to be on StackOverflow. Full credit to [blackk18](https://github.com/blackk18).

Comment: you should not change the code of that bundle directly though. fork it yourself or use a bundle that has this issue fixed already. Otherwise your composer might throw some errors about unsaved changes in that repository.

Comment: @byf-ferdy this is fixed in the master branch: https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/pull/200/files

Comment: @j0k Thanks very much, I will pull this down later.